# is there any workaround for returning the value of res from readCsv() method instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

the scenario is i am having the file uploader, which accept .json,.csv file after having file, If i clicked on upload button ,then homeComponent call the service dataparser , which is having two function readJson readCsv, and readcsv
function
returning the observable other one returns array ,this is simple i have to call the both function
on if else and handle the subscriber and array on HomeComponent
**But wait i do not want to handle these complexities at component level so i want to return only array of data on the home component page so, I have handle these on service but observable creating problem in this**

`**dataparser.service.ts having threee methods**`

```
async uploadDocument() {
const type = this.checkType();
if(!type) return;
 let m = type == "csv" ?  await this.readCsv() : await this.readJson();
 if(m){
  console.log(m);
  return m;
}
console.log(" m is empty");
}
```

**readJson method is returning array of objects and m is not empty if type of file is json its returning m to caller function on homeComponent**

```
private  readJson() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      const fr: FileReader = new FileReader();
      fr.readAsText(this.file);
      fr.onerror = () =>{
        fr.abort();
        reject(new DOMException("Problem parsing input  file."));
      }
      fr.onload = () =>{
        resolve(JSON.parse(fr.result as string));  
      }})
  }
```

readCsv method is returning empty varaiable(res) due to subscribe method is there any workaround through which i could get valve of res from readCsv function and **i do not want subscribe this method anywhere because i do not want handle these two result on homeComponent page, so then how can i get the value of this res varaible from readCsv**

```
private async readCsv() {
    let res: any[];
     this.ngxCsvParser.parse(this.file, { header: this.header, delimiter: ',' })
    .pipe().subscribe((result: Array<any>) => {
 
      // console.log('Result', result);
       res = result;
    }, (error: NgxCSVParserError) => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });
    if(res)
    {
      console.log(" i got m");
      return res;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're asking. What is the problem that the Subscribe method is introducing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot await Observables directly, however, you can `await` a Promise. You can simply use the .`toPromise()` method on the observables subscription. Consider the following:
const date = await dateSubscription.toPromise();

```
private async readCsv() {
    let res: any[];
   res= await this.ngxCsvParser.
     parse(this.file, { header: this.header, delimiter: ',' }).toPromise()
    if(res)
    {
      console.log(" i got m");
      return res;
    } 
  }
```